# Public constructor, can not create instance

Tags: java, inner-classes, instances

Have this code:

```
public final class A {
    public final class B {
    }
    public A(B b) {
    }
}
```

Problem:

1. You can not create an Instance of `A` without an instance of `B`.
2. You can not create an Instance of `B` without an instance of `A`.

Without changing the code and without reflection, how to create an Instance of `A`?

Comment: new A(new A.B()) ?

Comment: @Dinh That won't work, because `B()` cannot be used in a static context.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `null`:

```
new A(null);
```

---

Once you have an `A` object, you can create a `B` object too:

```
A a = new A(null);
B b = a.new B();
```

Comment: Ill wait a day for mark that as an answer to push upvotes in your direction ;D

Answer (score 3):

To expand on MC Emperor's answer, you can also create an instance of `A` with non null instance of `B` :

```
A a1 = new A(null);
B b1 = a1.new B();
A a2 = new A(b1);
```

and in a one liner:

```
A a = new A(new A(null).new B());
```